# Two different objects on the same socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, networking

Sender:

```
ObjectA A = new ObjectA();
ObjectB B = new ObjectB();
//Connection is created
socket.writeObject(B);
```

Receiver:

//don't know how to find to which object I should typecast the object to :(

Is there any way to send two different objects on the same Object stream?

-Pk

Comment: socket.writeObject(typeid + B); ???

Answer (score 4):

use `instanceof`

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
C c = new C();
 //say obj is the object you read from your socket.
if(a instanceof A){
      System.out.println("a is instance of A, obj can be cast as A");
      A remoteA = (A)obj; //wont throw classcast exception!!
}
if(b instanceof B){
      System.out.println("b is instance of B, obj can be cast as B");
      B remoteB = (B)obj; //wont throw classcast exception!!
}
if(c instanceof C){
      System.out.println("c is instance of C,obj can be cast as C"); 
      C remoteC = (C)obj;  //wont throw classcast exception!!
}
```

Are both the objects related? does one inherit the other? If so you'll need to check explicitly.

Say A (parent class) -> B

```
B b =  new B()
```

so `b instanceof B` and  `b instanceof A` will be true. So you need to be carefull. Check the child class first.

Comment: thanks for your time. I thing I dint post my question properly. I am sending this object over an object stream. I am sending two objects over the socket from the client side. On the server side I need to type cast it to the proper type. Hoe do I do this?

Comment: @Blacklabel, I got your question, and i answered correct, using `instanceof` you can determine what class the object belongs to, so if `instanceof A` is true, you can cast `(A)object`...it wont throw an exception. :) try it :) i'll modify the code, just incase.